# Printing PDF files with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to open a pdf file, print the file, and close Adobe Acrobat in Python 2.7.

```
import os

fd = os.startfile("temp.pdf", "print")
os.close(fd)
```

After running the code, I get the following error on the `os.close(fd)` line:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: `os.startfile` does not open a file, and it does not return a file descriptor that you can then pass to `os.close`. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: just remove `os.close()` you'll be fine. Just `os.startfile...`

Comment: For clarification, I want the pdf file to print, then Adobe Acrobat to close. If I only use os.startfile, Acrobat does not close.

Comment: Try using [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) using `start` command with with `shell=True`, waiting for enough time, then calling `.terminate()` on the process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the solution that I came up with:

```
    os.startfile("temp.pdf", "print")
    sleep(5)
    for p in psutil.process_iter(): #Close Acrobat after printing the PDF
        if 'AcroRd' in str(p):
            p.kill()
```

Comment: A bit late, but is there a way to pass arguments here, such as which printer, number of copies, or orientation?