# How to print a PDF file in django 2

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, printing, django-2.0

I am new in Django I try to develop a **POS** system where a user clicks on a button and a **PDF** will **print** I can generate PDF but I cannot **print** **that PDF**

Here is my code where I was trying to print the PDF file

```
import os
    def printPDf(request, id):
    context = AuthUser.objects.filter(id=id)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', {'context': context})
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    os.system('lp -d HPLaserJ {0}'.format(response.strip()))
```

Comment: Have you gone through this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/outputting-pdf/ ?

Comment: That page helps me to generate PDF files using Django. but I need to print that pdf file just a single clink on a button.

Comment: Read the line containing `Content-Disposition`

Comment: I'm new in Django and sorry to say It does not make any seance I can create a pdf file. I need to print that pdf file via a printer. would you please help me to do that with an example?

Comment: check this post this will help you i think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385324/printing-pdf-files-with-python